# How can I render a simple constructor in react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

/src/App.js
  Line 22:16:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

```
  20 | 
  21 | const App = () => {
> 22 |  constructor() {
     |                ^
  23 |      super()
  24 |      this.state = {
  25 |          input:
```

Comment: provide us your code

Comment: Can you provide source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add a constructor to a function - especially not to an arrow function. Constructor belongs to a class.

Comment: Thanks figured out that I should always use Class App extends component... And most importantly import component from react Before calling constructor. Thanks everyone